# how does JdbcRDD map to a KeyValue Pair RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have the following code:

```
val myRDD = new JdbcRDD( sc, () => r =>
(r.getString("city"),r.getString("town"),r.getInt("count")))
```

Because I need to reduceBy city and town to get the sum of count, so I need to create a key pair RDD with city and town as the key, count as the value. I tried `val pairRdd = myRDD.map(tp=>(tp._1,tp._2),tp._8))`, but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? Can you elaborate about what you mean with "it doesn't work"

Comment: Could you correct your code? There is no way it can even compile :)

Comment: Thank you guys, I found it's Eclipse compile issue, there was no prompt, so I thought it's not a KeyValue pair RDD.